# MySaifu JVM and BlueCove API on an iPAQ

Tags: windows-mobile, jvm, bluetooth

Having a bit of an issue running BlueCove on my iPAQ (h5550). I
installed MySaifu JVM and added the BlueCove jar library to the classpath,
but whenever I try to run the tester jar or any other files that reference the
BlueCove API, I get class not found exceptions.

Anyone had the same issues? I know from the BlueCove documentation
that it's been tested on MySaifu on Windows CE, a name sometimes
(confusingly) used interchangeably with Windows Mobile and Pocket PC,
so maybe it's just a case of compatibility?

Any help would be appreciated.

SUMMARY:

- Bluecove not working after being added to MySaifu classpath

  - Class not found exceptions
- iPAQ h5550

  - Windows Mobile 2003 (Pocket PC)

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I tested MySaifu JVM and it didn't seem to have a complete imlementation of the CDC Personal Profile 1.1 (the most complete). I don't know what J2ME profile does that program need but problems could start from that point.

Other issue is that not all Windows CD/Mobile platforms are identical so what runs ok on a Windows Mobile 2003 PDA may not work on another Windows Mobile 2003 PDA.

If you plan to develop enterprise-grade Java applications the only acceptable choice today is the [IBM Everyplace WebSphere Micro Envinronment](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/wireless/weme/) (previously known as J9 JVM), which is not free though the license is pretty inexpensive.

Anyway if you plan to stick to MySaifu pasting the exception would help to clarify where the error is.